# MultiMonitorTool.exe questions

Tags: windows, display, batch-file, switch

I am using Multimonitortool.exe to switch between displays, to be precise: i got 3 Monitors, while Monitor 1 and 2 are permanentely on and Monitor 3 is turned on only when i need it. If i need it, monitor 3 also has to be my Main display. So i need to enable my 3rd monitor and make it my main display. After usage i want to make Monitor 1 my Maindisplay again and monitor 3 has to be disconnected again.
I want to use two bat files for that with Multimonitortool:

1. For enabling Monitor 3 and making it the main display i use:

   ```
    MultiMonitorTool.exe /enable \\.\DISPLAY3

    MultiMonitorTool.exe /SetPrimary \\.\DISPLAY3
   ```
2. for making monitor 1 the main display and disconnecting monitor 3

   ```
   MultiMonitorTool.exe /SetPrimary \\.\DISPLAY1

   MultiMonitorTool.exe /disable \\.\DISPLAY3
   ```

This works to some degree, but the main display switch does not work. Monitor 2 automatically becomes my main monitor in both cases.

Comment: Maybe the operations are not finished when the next one starts. Just to try, create 4 batch files, then manually start the ones you need.

Comment: It would perhaps be simpler to use the Multimonitortool commands of `SaveConfig` and `LoadConfig`.

Comment: Iagree with Daniel B here. You can also induce a fake delay by using the following command: `ping 127.0.0.1 -n 3 >nul` replace the 3 with the amount of seconds you want to wait.

Comment: The delay does not work for some reason, it still makes my 2nd monitor my main monitor, even if i add 10 seconds of delay. Thanks though. The config loading seems easier, yes, is there a way to use this with one click/command, like a macro on a keyboard or such? EDIT: But i think i can live with that since i can use shortcuts with MMTool to load the files, saves quite a bit of clicking in the control panel with the screen flickering after every change in the settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simpler to use the
[MultiMonitorTool](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/multi_monitor_tool.html)
commands of `SaveConfig` and `LoadConfig`:

> /SaveConfig
>
> Saves the current configuration of all your monitors into the
> specified filename, including the screen resolution, colors depth, and
> monitor position. You can load the saved configuration back into the
> system by using the /LoadConfig command-line option.
>
> Example: `MultiMonitorTool.exe /SaveConfig "c:\temp\monitors1.cfg"`
>
> /LoadConfig
>
> Loads the monitors configuration that you previouly saved with
> /SaveConfig
>
> Example: `MultiMonitorTool.exe /LoadConfig "c:\temp\monitors1.cfg"`

You may create batch files on the desktop that contain these
commands and also assign them keyboard shortcuts for ease
of use.