# Switch screen being mirrored by command line

Tags: windows, powershell, display, batch-file, script

In my setup I have two monitors stacked vertically, and a TV, hooked up to my PC. The TV mirrors the top screen usually. I want to write a script (so that I can set a keybind) to switch the screen it mirrors (be it the top or the bottom) easily instead of clicking through the settings panel every time. How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: Look at the tool mentioned in this question: https://superuser.com/questions/1812968/multimonitortool-exe-questions